# Windows appsettings management and deployment

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis, configuration

I'm trying to rationalize the usefulness of config file transforms to make deployment easy, vs the security of leaving connection strings inside source control. Currently there are publish profiles for staging/deployment servers, which have all the config (connection string) to point to the correct databases. Coming from using PaaS products like heroku, I've had it drilled into me that this is a bad thing, but there's no easy way to 12 factor up a windows app.

Is there any good way of separating my config from my source code in windows?.

Ideally I would like the server itself to hold the config (like ENV vars do on heroku).

<s>Closest Idea I have at the moment is setting up SQL client aliases using cli-config, and then storing all other DB in the database. So I will just have aliases for apps ( MYAPP_PRODUCTION) in the connection string. Of course any application that doesn't use a database won't have this, so theres also that.</s>. Apparently cliconfg doesn't let me put in security connection information.

I've also thought about setting up the publish profiles in a secondary repository as a git submodule (so its a 'config' repo), but that seems a tad complicated. Configuration changes get tied to source code commits? (seems ew).

Last idea I've had was a configuration service, so the apps connect to that and get their config, but then securing that would require the app to provide a apikey of sorts (don't want app A reading app Bs configuration do we), and I am right back where I started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have settled on with this, is using environment variables.

Its an absolute pain under windows, but with IIS you can specify `load user profile` for an application pool. This creates a windows virtual account, that you can use regedit to set the environment variables for.

It's not pretty, but it works, and it keeps our environmental configuration out of source code and out of build servers.